# Why are ArrayAdapters specialized for TextViews?

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter

I'm working on an Android project, and we have many many different compound data types that require custom array adapters. There's a bunch of boilerplate type stuff we have to do to back-adapt "generic" behavior, that allows us to send in these compound data types.

I had a look at the implementation of `ArrayAdapter`, and found this:

```
private View createViewFromResource(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent,
        int resource) {
    View view;
    TextView text;

    if (convertView == null) {
        view = mInflater.inflate(resource, parent, false);
    } else {
        view = convertView;
    }

    try {
        if (mFieldId == 0) {
            //  If no custom field is assigned, assume the whole resource is a TextView
            text = (TextView) view;
        } else {
            //  Otherwise, find the TextView field within the layout
            text = (TextView) view.findViewById(mFieldId);
        }
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        Log.e("ArrayAdapter", "You must supply a resource ID for a TextView");
        throw new IllegalStateException(
                "ArrayAdapter requires the resource ID to be a TextView", e);
    }

    T item = getItem(position);
    if (item instanceof CharSequence) {
        text.setText((CharSequence)item);
    } else {
        text.setText(item.toString());
    }

    return view;
}
```

As you can see, the `ArrayAdapter` class is geared specifically to creating views with single `TextView`s. This seems to me a fairly large design flaw since it should have been obvious that not all `ArrayAdapter`s are going to be dealing solely with text. If I were able to fix it, I would make the current ArrayAdapter implementation (dealing with TextViews) as a specialization of a more generic ArrayAdapter.

Am I missing something? Why was this design decision made? Is there some standard or accepted way around this?

Comment: use `SimpleAdapter` then, by default it uses a list of Maps but it would be easy to make it work with a list of POJO or something

Comment: @pskink Didn't even know that this class existed!

Comment: but.... i would consider `SimpleCursorAdapter` ... what is your data model? sqlite db?

Comment: @pskink Yes, we are using a SQLite DB, but we're not directly querying it for the data. Our data gets parsed from binary TCP responses from a server. Our program then parses it and stores it in SQLite DB, but purely for offline data access at this point.

Comment: so use only `SimpleCursorAdapter` it has well defined interface: `Cursor` so it is extremely easy for use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> As you can see, the ArrayAdapter class is geared specifically to creating views with single TextViews.

No, it is not. It is geared specifically for handling item views that have 1+ `TextView` widgets, alongside possibly other widgets.

> This seems to me a fairly large design flaw since it should have been obvious that not all ArrayAdapters are going to be dealing solely with text.

There is nothing in `ArrayAdapter` that limits it to "dealing solely with text". It does have a limitation that you cannot use the inherited `getView()` if your item view has zero `TextView` widgets (or widgets that inherit from `TextView`). Ideally, `ArrayAdapter` would check for a `null` widget and just roll along. Ideally, I would have hair.

Second, at the time that Android was first developed, a bit shy of a decade ago, the predominant `ListView` content *was* "solely... text". Please remember that the devices of a decade ago were dealing with CPUs with only a few percent of the power of today's mobile devices (e.g., 66MHz single-core). UIs simply were not that sophisticated.

> If I were able to fix it, I would make the current ArrayAdapter implementation (dealing with TextViews) as a specialization of a more generic ArrayAdapter.

That is called `BaseAdapter`.

Note that in the `RecyclerView` world, there *is* no `ArrayAdapter` equivalent — you are working with something more akin to `BaseAdapter`.

> Why was this design decision made?

Build yourself a time machine, go back in time to 2005-2007, and ask the Android developers then why they did it this way. Otherwise, we would need to close this question, on the grounds that you're seeking opinions.

> Is there some standard or accepted way around this?

Either:

- Do not chain to the inherited `getView()`, if it will not meet your needs (no `TextView`, need multiple item view layouts, etc.), or
- Allow `ArrayAdapter` to handle the one `TextView`, while you handle the rest, or
- Use `BaseAdapter` for your own arbitrary collections, or
- Use other subclasses of `BaseAdapter`, whether from Android or third parties, or
- Switch to `RecyclerView`

Comment: Thank you for the comprehensive response. I will try not to ask speculative questions in the future.

Comment: @cmbasnett: I wouldn't phrase it as "speculative" so much as "all but impossible to answer authoritatively". Occasionally, you know that the decision-makers are likely to see the SO question, in which case "why was this design decision made?" questions are reasonable. Besides, maybe you *do* have a time machine and are bored with all the standard tropes for what you should do with one... :-)